# How to search a string for a match of "string" from 0000 and 9999

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string (filename) that may include a frame number. If present, that number should be anywhere from and including 0000 to 9999. I know how to find a match for 0 to 9999. But it specifically need to find a4 digit match.

So this is not how I want it to work...

```
var fileName = "Ext 01_main Concept A0000"

for (var i = 0; i < 9999; i++){
   if (fileName.indexOf([i]) != -1) {
   var frame = i;
   }
}
```

In this case, frame needs to be "0000"
Does any have suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: If there is a number is it always at the very end?

Comment: Go read up on regular expressions, matching a four-digit number is pretty trivial using those.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage regular expressions to test the string for and extract a 4-digit number:

```js
var fileName = "Ext 01_main Concept A0000"
console.log(fileName.match(/\d{4}/)); // result: [ 0000 ]
```

If the 4-digit number in question will always appear at the end of the string, you could also use the `$` token to ensure that the 4-digit number in question appears as such:

```js
var fileName = "Ext 01_main Concept A0000"
console.log(fileName.match(/\d{4}$/)); // result: [ 0000 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can regex the number from the string and test that:

```js
 var fileName = "Ext 01_main Concept A0000"
const regex = /\d{4}/; // if it's always the last, it could be /\d{4}$/

thenum = parseInt(fileName.match(regex)[0],10); // "0000"
console.log( thenum > 0 && thenum < 9999 );
```

Your code might work, but worst case it performs 9998 unneeded checks!

Answer (score -1):

you can do this using a regexp:

```
var fileName = "Ext 01_main Concept A0000";
// The regexp will search for any 4 digits from 0000 to 9999 
var match = fileName.match(/[0-9]{4}/g);
// The variable match will have an array with all matching values
// In this case the log should write [ '0000' ]
console.log(match);
```